# How to open container based on dropd own?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on an application that would allow the user to select different options. One of them being a drop down. How would I go about implementing it so that if they select the drop down item "Fall Victim" the window container "Fall Victim" would open. I would do an if statement but there are over 30 items in the drop down box.

Answer (score 0):

you can map your form name with the dropdown item name. as user selects the dropdwon item,
search the dictionary using below code

double myKey = dic1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == 
          dropdownitemtext).Value;

and mykey will have the mapped containername and you can show it,

just a rough logic.